# No response from FT230X using Android D2XX driver

Tags: android, usbserial, ftdi, d2xx

I have made a simple Android app that connects to an FTDI chip using the [D2XX driver](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX/Android_Java_D2xx_2.04.zip) and writes a command and listens for responses.

Using this app I can successfully write some dummy data to an [FT232B](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT232B.htm) chip and receive a response.

With the same app I am not getting any response from an [FT230X](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT230X.html) chip (which has a different firmware). I have verified that all configuration was successfully set and that a connection to the chip is opened. I can also confirm that writing to the chip seems to work (at least the `write()` operation returned `true`).

At this point I don't know whether it is the firmware that is broken or my app.

**Any ideas what could be wrong or what my next step should be?**

Edit:

- I used a Samsung S7 Edge (with OTG-adapter) on Android 6.0.1
- I have tried both an older D2XX version (2013) and a newer (2015-10-21) with the same results.

Comment: when you write, does the result take effect in the device that uses the chip? are you sure the write is successful on the chip side not just android side?

Comment: I don't know if it has an effect on the chip side unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set a specific baudrate that this firmware could handle. The underlying chip accepted other baudrates though.